# Is it possible to change NaN string representation?

Tags: scala

When converting `NaN` value to string it simply gives `"NaN"`. Is there a way to change that?

Something like (not working due to reassignment to val error):

```
Double.NaN.toString = () => "???"
```

Comment: write your own function that takes doubles and converts them to strings, and call it in those places where you'd like a different representation?

Comment: Can you give more context about the situation in which you want this to operate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an implicit class that you bring into scope and then add a new method to it to give you the properly formatted string given the NaN case.  Something like this:

```
object Implicits {
  implicit class PimpedDouble(d:Double){
    def toFormattedString = 
      if (d.isNaN) "something else other than NaN"
      else d.toString
  }
}

object TestDouble extends App{
  import Implicits._

  val dub = Double.NaN 
  println(dub.toFormattedString)
  println(1.234.toFormattedString)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, however overriding `toString` itself is not possible?